# In Altium Designer, how can you set the autotracer to route all traces with as equal lengths as possible?

Tags: pcb, altium, delay, trace, propagation

Note that this board does not require a power or ground plane, since it's just used to bridge two boards. I want the traces to be as equal in length as possible in order to minimize any difference in voltage propagation speed between any two traces. Thanks.

Comment: \[Insert snark here about how autorouters are useless\]

Comment: [Agree with Connor Wolf and add more snarky comments about autorouters]

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to define a Matched Net Length Rule (Design -> Rules) where as "First Object" you will need to define all your Tracks. A query like "IsTrack" might be enough. Alternatively you can place all the tracks which need to be length matched into a net class and then define InNetClass('YourNetClass') as query. Set the tolerance to a value of your choice.

If the Autorouter doesn't obey these settings (I'm not quite sure about it) you can use the interactive length matching command (Tools -> Equalize Net Lengths) or the Interactive Length Tuning Tool (Tools -> Interactive Length Tuning Tool).